# How to retain N smallest elements in a given row of numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, sorting, import

Given a 2-D numpy matrix, how to retain the N smallest elements in each row and change rest of them to `0`(zero).

For example: `N=3`
Input array:

```
1   2   3   4   5
4   3   6   1   0
6   5   3   1   2
```

Expected output:

```
1   2   3   0   0
0   3   0   1   0
0   0   3   1   2
```

Following is the code that I have tried and it works:

```
# distance_matrix is the given 2D array
N=3
for i in range(distance_matrix.shape[0]):
    n_th_largest = np.sort(distance_matrix[i])[N]
    for j in range(distance_matrix.shape[1]):
        distance_matrix[i][j] = np.where(distance_matrix[i][j]<n_th_largest,distance_matrix[i][j],0)

# return distance_matrix
```

However, this operation involves iterating over every single element. Is there a faster way to solve this using `np.argsort()` or any other function?

Comment: If this was `pandas`, we'd define a custom function and `.apply()` it to each row. It would be a much clearer idiom, possibly slightly slower code.

Comment: Do you only want answers that assume the input must be positive integers, all values distinct, no ties?

Comment: Well, this is for getting the K nearest neighbors in KNN algorithm. That way, all the distances are positives, and ties are possible but we need a maximum of N max/min numbers in a given row.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Approach #1**

Here's one with [`np.argpartition`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argpartition.html) for performance efficiency -

```
N = 3
newval = 0
np.put_along_axis(a,np.argpartition(a,N,axis=1)[:,N:],newval,axis=1)
```

**Explanation :** We partition the input array to get indices that are *partitioned-across* for the `kth` argument in `np.argpartition`. So, basically consider this as two partitions, with first one for smallest N elements along that axis and the other for the rest. We need to reset the second partition, which we select with `[:,N:]` and we use [`np.put_along_axis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.put_along_axis.html) to do the resetting.

Sample run -

```
In [144]: a # input array
Out[144]: 
array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [4, 3, 6, 1, 0],
       [6, 5, 3, 1, 2]])

In [145]: np.put_along_axis(a,np.argpartition(a,3,axis=1)[:,3:],0,axis=1)

In [146]: a
Out[146]: 
array([[1, 2, 3, 0, 0],
       [0, 3, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 3, 1, 2]])
```

**Approach #2**

Here's another again with `np.argpartition`, but just slicing the Nth smallest element per row and then resetting all greater than it. As such, if there are duplicates for the Nth smallest element, we will keep all those with this method. Here's the implementation -

```
a[a>=a[np.arange(len(a)), np.argpartition(a,3,axis=1)[:,3],None]] = 0
```

Timings on a scaled up version -

```
In [184]: a = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5],[4,3,6,1,0],[6,5,3,1,2]])

In [185]: a = np.repeat(a,10000,axis=0)

In [186]: %timeit np.put_along_axis(a,np.argpartition(a,3,axis=1)[:,3:],0,axis=1)
1.78 ms ± 5.89 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [187]: a = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5],[4,3,6,1,0],[6,5,3,1,2]])

In [188]: a = np.repeat(a,10000,axis=0)

In [189]: %timeit a[a>=a[np.arange(len(a)), np.argpartition(a,3,axis=1)[:,3],None]] = 0
1.54 ms ± 54.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: It works, but could you please explain how it works? Upvoted, I need to wait for 3 minutes before I can accept the answer. Will accept it later.

Comment: @AshwinGeetD'Sa Added `Explanation`. For more info on argparition, nothing better than the linked docs.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 1):

If we can use `pandas` and have your input in a dataframe, this is a one-liner with `.apply(..., axis=1)` on each row:

```
df.apply(lambda row: row.nsmallest(3), axis=1).fillna(0).astype(int)

   0  1  2  3  4
0  1  2  3  0  0
1  0  3  0  1  0
2  0  0  3  1  2
```

Notes:

- If there can be ties, [`nsmallest()` has a `keep` argument specifying how to handle them](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nsmallest.html)
- In this case you need an `.astype(int)`, since introducing the NaNs causes the dtype to be coerced up to float. You could avoid that if you wrote a custom function to replace with zeros.

And here's the boilerplate to make your example reproducible:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

dat = """1   2   3   4   5
4   3   6   1   0
6   5   3   1   2"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(dat), sep='\s+', header=None)
```

Comment: Well, your answer might be correct, however, I have already accepted previous answer. I appreciate your help and have upvoted the answer for your efforts.

Comment: Ashwin that's fine, just showing you the pandas version is elegant.